# Replace html with values inside html tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to log messages from a chat box that includes embedded images.

What I currently have is able to capture all the text, but the images are not captured.

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        if (mutation.addedNodes.length){
            //console.log(mutation)
            console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0].innerText)
        }
    })
})

const chat = document.querySelector('div#messagebuffer')
observer.observe(chat, {
    childList: true
})
```

The innerHTML from the nodes produces something similar to

```
<span class="timestamp">[19:09:36] </span><span><img class="channel-emote" src="https://website.com" title="/image"> Lorem Ipsum <img class="channel-emote" src="https://website.com" title="/image2"></span>
```

Basically I would like to parse the title values in the html and keep the text to look something like

```
[19:09:36] /image Lorem Ipsum /image2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have IMG tags and spans you can do something like this. 
but because of how the markup of your text is structured the `span` for the date is in a separate mutation from the `span` for the images and text. This mean you'll still have to modify the following code if you wan the date and the text to be logged in a single line.
You can easily do that by checking the class of your spans and refreshing the array based on that but that's totally up to you. 
Or if possible, you can have the date `span` as a sibling of the images and text.

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
   mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    let txtArr = []
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
     mutation.addedNodes[0].childNodes.forEach((node)=>{
      if(node.nodeName == "IMG"){
       txtArr.push(node.title)
      }else{
       txtArr.push(node.wholeText)
      }
       
     })
     
     console.log(txtArr.join(''))
    }
   })
  })
```